# indexof is not a function in typescript while filter based on number

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

When i try to filter month value on dropdown it shows indexof() is  not function ..
The code is ..

```
@Pipe({
    name: "monthFilter",
})
export class MonthStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(array: any[], query: number): any {  
        console.log("query", query);
        if (query) {
            return _.filter(array, row => row.LicenseMonth.indexOf(query) > -1);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Is there any alternative method to filter dropdown based on values..

My json data are:

```
{
    "BusinessId": 1549,
    "OrganizationNumber": "992060867",
    "CompanyName": "Litra Containerservice AS ",
    "Address": "Industrigata 62",
    "Zipcode": "2619 Lillehammer",
    "Mobile": "98238925",
    "Telephone": "66789485",
    "ConnectedTo": "Admin",
    "ConnectedToId": "123",
    "HSEManager": "Marina Magerøy",
    "BusinessContact": "Lars Andre Skogstad",
    "ContactMobile": "48499613",
    "BusinessContactTelephone": "45283769",
    "NoOfEmployees": "15",
    "Status": "Active",
    "ModifiedOn": "2016-10-01T23:55:01.033",
    "LicenseMonth": 10,
    "Category": "Godstransport på vei"
  },
```

Comment: **LicenseMonth** refers to? add your json data

Comment: Probably because it's a number. try `('' + row.LicenseMonth).indexOf(...)`

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The JSON you have attached is an object not an array. `indexOf` is only present on Arrays, not on objects.

Comment: no its an array ...i just typed single objects...

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the fact that `LicenseMonth` is actually a number.

this should work:

```
@Pipe({name: 'monthFilter'})
export class MonthStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(arr: any[], num?: number): any {
        return typeof num !== 'undefined' 
           ? arr.filter(e => e.LicenseMonth === num)
           : arr;
    }
}
```

I would also like to suggest a more generic approach, instead of using a specific pipe for a specific field.

You could instead write a more generic solution.
For example:

`<p>{{ rows | filterBy: ['LicenseMonth']: 42  }}</p>`

It's possible to write your own version of it, or to use a library I wrote with bunch of useful pipes.

#### `ngx-pipes`: https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes

filterBy pipe: https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#filterby